# Use the Gregorian, Jalali and Hijiri calendars in the application

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, gregorian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I need a Date picker to be able to set it's time types(Gregorian,Jalali or Hijiri)from setting and change it to each others too... and all the items that work by DATE will get new value...as I didn't have found any library to do this i tried to ask best Coders to help me by their libraries...if your answer is yes then how is possible to change all the dates by changing the type of calendar?
some one said "use joda time Library" but there is no tutorial.is joda time Ok?

پی نوشت : please comment up if you have same BROBLEM...to ANSWER]أۀ(in fa) sooner

Comment: You could use my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) which offers support for all three calendars, for example [Jalali](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/PersianCalendar.html). Another option is ICU4J. About `DatePicker`-support, I think here you have to develop your own picker.

Comment: Since you are ask about Joda-Time, it’s legacy now and doesn’t offer a Jalali calendar. Otherwise it’s certainly OK. It’s an option. I would research other options too.

Comment: I am not as good as write a jalali or hijti calendar...i need all ..is it possible to save dates for example to jalali and convert it each time that user need to use date?